# Regular expressions: Understanding non-greedy repetition

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does the regular expression pattern `/y+?z/` match the entire string `yyyz`?

My understand is the pattern `/y+z/` is **greedy** so will match one or more `y` characters followed by a single `z` character. To make this expression non-greedy (match the first instance of `y` only) I can introduce a `?` character immediately after the `+` character. For example `/y+?z/`. Now, I would expect this pattern to match the string `yz`. However, this isn't the case. Instead, the entire string `yyyz` is matched.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of difference when you're applying the quantifier to a specific character. It's a lot clearer what the difference is when the quantifier is applied to something that can match many different characters.

Comment: @TimPietzcker your answer has explained it for me. Will accept in ~8 minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex matches always start at the earliest possible position, which is the first `y`. Since the only way to match the `z` part of the regex is to match all the intervening `y`s as well, the regex will match the entire string.

Lazy evaluation doesn't mean "match as few as possible" but "match as few as possible to complete the match from the current position".

Comment: The current position being the first `y`?

Comment: @henrywright: Right, the regex engine works its way through the string from left to right and attempts a match at every position, until it finds a match. Since there *is* a valid match starting at the first `y`, that's the one it finds.